# How do I find x given y or vice versa in numpy?

Tags: search, numpy, numerical-methods

For example, I have the following arrays:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5]
y = [2, 8, 3, 7,   8, 1]
```

I would like to be able to do the following given `x`:

```
>>> what_is_y_when_x_is(2)
(2, 3)
>>> what_is_y_when_x_is(3.1) # Perhaps set rules to round to nearest (or up or down)
(3, 7)
```

On the other hand, when given `y`:

```
>>> what_is_x_when_y_is(2)
(0, 2)
>>> what_is_x_when_y_is(max(y))
([1, 4.5], 8)
```

### The circumstances of this problem

I could have plotted `y` versus `x` using a closed analytical function, which should be very easy by just calling `foo_function(x)`. However, I'm running **numerical simulations** whose data plots do not have closed analytical solutions.

### Attempted solution

I've tackled similar problems before and approached them roughly this way:

`what_is_y_when_x_is(some_x)`

1. Search the array `x` for `some_x`.
2. Get its index, `i`.
3. Pick up `y[i]`.

### Question

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a built-in `numpy` function or a better algorithm?

Comment: I can think of only one more efficient solution: sort your arrays, then use lnear interpolation to find the most probable index for y (or x, respectively), then start going further and further from that initial guess until you reach the destination.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [scipy.interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) module?  For your use case I think several of the functions would be mode useful in practice than simply rounding to the nearest (although you could do that too.)

Answer (score 5):

You should look at numpy.searchsorted and also numpy.interp. Both of those look like they might do the trick. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5])
y = np.array([2, 8, 3, 7,   8, 1])

# y should be sorted for both of these methods
order = y.argsort()
y = y[order]
x = x[order]

def what_is_x_when_y_is(input, x, y):
    return x[y.searchsorted(input, 'left')]

def interp_x_from_y(input, x, y):
    return np.interp(input, y, x)

print what_is_x_when_y_is(7, x, y)
# 3
print interp_x_from_y(1.5, x, y)
# 2.5
```

Comment: @Stryker why? Do you have a problem with methods :)

Comment: I don't have a problem with methods :) . It is just that I tried the code order = y.argsort() and it did not work. so I had to change it to order = np.argsort(y) in ipython notebook. :)

Comment: @Stryker `y.argsort()` should work if `y` is an array, arrays have an `argsort` method. If `y` is something else, like a list, you can always use `np.argsort(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module for this. This is pure python - no numpy here:

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5]
>>> y = [2, 8, 3, 7,   8, 1]
>>> x_lookup = sorted(zip(x, y))
>>> y_lookup = sorted(map(tuple, map(reversed, zip(x, y))))
>>> 
>>> import bisect
>>> def pair_from_x(x):
...    return x_lookup[min(bisect.bisect_left(x_lookup, (x,)), len(x_lookup)-1)]
... 
>>> def pair_from_y(y):
...    return tuple(reversed(y_lookup[min(bisect.bisect_left(y_lookup, (y,)), len(y_lookup)-1)]))
...
```

And some examples of using it:

```
>>> pair_from_x(0)
(0, 2)
>>> pair_from_x(-2)
(0, 2)
>>> pair_from_x(2)
(2, 3)
>>> pair_from_x(3)
(3, 7)
>>> pair_from_x(7)
(5, 1)
>>> 
>>> pair_from_y(0)
(5, 1)
>>> pair_from_y(1)
(5, 1)
>>> pair_from_y(3)
(2, 3)
>>> pair_from_y(4)
(3, 7)
>>> pair_from_y(8)
(1, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you described is, as far as I'm considered, a good way. I'm not sure if you are, but I think you could use the .index(...) method on your array:

```
>>> li
['I', 'hope', 'this', 'answer', 'helps', 'you']
>>> li.index("hope")
1
```

Other than that, you might want to consider one array op "Points" which have an x and a y, though I'm not sure if this is possible of course. That way you won't have to keep two arrays in sync (same number of elements).

Comment: The `.index()` method returns the index of only the first match it finds, which also leads to the question: "What if there is no exact match?"

Comment: You are totally right, then I would consider the "Point" thingy, and just iterate over the single list, check all the x values, and add their y values to an array. Then return this array. If there are no matching values it'll just return an empty array, which makes sense. Do the same for checking y-values. (The same thing is possible with an x-array and a y-array, though I think it's cleaner of you use "Points")

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your pipeline. You can write a snippet base on [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to implement it efficiently. Note that you will have to pass your lists as numpy arrays first (this can be included in the function).

Below is an example of a function doing the job, with an option to round the target (I have included a `which array` argument, so everything can be done in just one function, whatever you want to search in x or y). Note that one of the output will be a numpy array, so modify it to convert it to anything you want (liste, tuple, etc ...).

```
import numpy as np

def pick(x_array, y_array, target, which_array='x', round=True):
    # ensure that x and y are numpy arrays
    x_array, y_array = np.array(x_array), np.array(y_array) 

    # optional: round to the nearest. True by default
    if round==True:
        target = np.round(target) 

    if which_array == 'x': # look for the target in x_array
        return target, y_array[np.where(x_array == target)[0]]
    if which_array == 'y': # look for the target in y_array
        return x_array[np.where(y_array == target)[0]], target
```

Results given by your examples:

```
# >>> what_is_y_when_x_is(2)
pick(x, y, 2, 'x')
(2, array([3]))

# >>> what_is_y_when_x_is(3.1)
pick(x, y, 3.1, 'x')
3.0, array([7]))

# >>> what_is_y_when_x_is(2)
pick(x, y, 2, 'y')
(array([ 0.]), 2)

# >>> what_is_x_when_y_is(max(y))
pick(x, y, max(y), 'y')
(array([ 1. ,  4.5]), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised version of code provided by @ Bi Rico:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5])
y = np.array([2, 8, 3, 7,   8, 1])

# y should be sorted for both of these methods
order = np.argsort(y)
y = y[order]
x = x[order]

def what_is_x_when_y_is(input, x, y):
    return x[y.searchsorted(input, 'left')]

print(what_is_x_when_y_is(7, x, y))
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def what_is_y_when_x_is(value, x, y, tolerance=1e-3):
    return [(xi, yi) for (xi, yi) in zip(x, y) if abs(xi - value) <= tolerance]
```

Notice that rather than comparing for equality the code above performs a "close enough" equality test. The **default tolerance** is set up to 0.001 (you can use any other value). Here are some examples of use:

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5]
>>> y = [2, 8, 3, 7,   8, 1]
>>> what_is_y_when_x_is(0, x, y)
[(0, 2)]
>>> what_is_y_when_x_is(1, x, y, tolerance=.1)
[(1, 8)]
>>> what_is_y_when_x_is(2, x, y, tolerance=1)
[(1, 8), (2, 3), (3, 7)]
>>> what_is_y_when_x_is(4, x, y, tolerance=.5)
[(4.5, 8)]
```